# findAutocompletePredictionsFromQuery doesn't seem to work in the pod version 3.5 of Google Places

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-places-api

This problem is occurring while trying to use the Google Places iOS SDK on the latest version.

Add `pod 'GooglePlaces', '3.5.0'` to your pod file.

Install the pod and try to compile a project that had google places autocomplete prior.

It will remove the previous `GMSPlacesClient` `autocompleteQuery` function from usability, but then when searching for the replacement found [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration), the `findAutocompletePredictionsFromQuery` is also not usable.

[image]

I am using Cocoapods version 1.8.4 on Catalina. I don't believe this is an environment issue though. If anyone has any idea how to update to GooglePlaces 3.5, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems they haven't updated the documentation yet. That func has been renamed again.

You need to do 2 things:

1) import GoogleMapsBase

2) use findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: ... ) instead

Comment: That is not the case. `findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: ... )` was the original and got changed to `findAutocompletePredictionsFromQuery`. I dug into their SDK and found `findAutocompletePredictionsFromQuery`, but for whatever reason when I use it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Now I feel dumb. This is what I get for not investing more time in Objc Syntax.